# Installing Ubuntu on a Surface Pro 9 in Dual Boot with Windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows, surface

I booted from an USB and Ubuntu installed but after a kernel update, nothing worked so I had to reinstall Windows 11. So the only system right now is Windows 11. While trying to reinstall Ubuntu,  the system gets stuck at the Windows Logo when I try to boot from an USB. Is there any solution to this problem? I have a Surface Pro 9.

Comment: If you’re getting a windows logo when trying to boot Ubuntu from usb, the bios is going straight to windows boot loader. (1) make sure in Windows fast start up is off, then completely shut down (not restart) your system, then try turning it on; (2) make sure usb is the first boot option in your hardware setup.

Comment: To fix surface bugs, use https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Surface-Pro-9 . Install the linux-surface PPA, and their kernel, then report bugs to the GitHub issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you’re facing this issue https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/1274

Hope this solves your issue as it did mine on a Surface Pro 9.